# dependency walker gives me errors on the system that runs correctly

Tags: .net, dll, windows-runtime

I have a missing dll on a system. I have the following message:

Could not load file or assembly 'mydll.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Of course, 'mydll' is present there, it most probably is another dll on which it depends. I downloaded dependency walker to check what it could be. I have first tested it in another system, where the application has no problems. But if I open mydll.dll with dependency walker on the system where my application does work, it reports eight dlls that should be missing. So I would assume these dlls have nothing to do with the problem, but can somebody please confirm that, and explain why they are reported? Is it normal that these dlls are reported as missing, and can I consider the messages as a 'false positive'?

These are the files reported as 'missing', while my application does work on thát system:

- API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
- DCOMP.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL

Comment: I think I can pretty sure those dlls above had nothing to do with the actual problem. I think they are some dlls missing since the application is developed for a 32bits system and I am working on 64bits. The real problem was that I missed msvcr120.dll. A lib distributable for visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are some dlls in the RT version of windows that had nothing to do with the actually problem. These dlls are never called on a normal desktop I think.