# The specified procedure could not be found - how to identify?

Tags: dll, process, include, dependencies, runtime-error

I'm developing plugins for a program. Whenever I try to load my plugin in that program it crashes with an `the specified procedure could not be found`but nothing more.

Well to have an insight I tracked with `Process Monitor` (or ProcMon). I set the filter to just print messages for the process of my main program. However that application shows me including the libraries ends (after wandering through PATH) at the right file - i.e. Result: SUCCESS.

So my computer left me pretty clueless, yet refuses to work. Has anyone an idea how identify the missing procedure?

**N.B.:**  Additionally I ran the `DependencyWalker` which gave me the usual error message because it's deprecated ([dependency walker gives me errors on the system that runs correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863297/dependency-walker-gives-me-errors-on-the-system-that-runs-correctly)) - which *could* indicate that all dependencies are found.